# connect layer-3 switch stack's, lacp or ospf

Tags: networking

I have a main and several satellite site's.

Between the main and the satellite site's, there are 2 physical links.

all site's have 2 layer-3 switches that are capable of

- dt-LACP (an LACP trunk, connected to the 2 layer3-switches)
- ospf

These switches are not in a switch-stack in the Cisco/3Com way (configurable as one switch), but are separate switches with a Switch-Interconnect. Router redundancy is achieved using VRRP.

Should I connect the sites with

- a dt-LACP LAG
- create a OSPF network between all 4 Layer-3 switches

http://thomasr.home.xs4all.nl/netwerk-ontwerp.jpg

Comment: LACP is link aggregation.  OSPF is a routing protocol.  I'm confused on your question.

Comment: What switch manufacturer/model are you using?

Comment: I've got HP Procurve 3500's and Dell Force 10 S4820T's (one type in each pair :-)

Comment: @ewwhite: I know LACP and OSPF are very different technologies, but I think I can make two very different solutions to the same problem.
- Will each work
- what would be the better solution, and why?
LACP seems to be the simpeler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dt-LACP seems to be HPs Distributed Trunking.
According to [an answer](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03269076&sp4ts.oid=3457354) at the HP Support Center, Distributed Trunking is only meant for server-to-switch-connections, not switch-to-switch.

Considering that your four switches are non-stacked (at least in my terminology), standard L3 routed links with OSPF for dynamic routing would be my choice.